# how to install snap on amazon linux 2

Tags: amazon-linux-2, amazon-workspaces

How can I install snap on my amazon linux 2?

I've gone through a few links on the web:

- https://github.com/albuild/snap
- https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-install-snapd-on-amazon-linux-2/20824/4

I can't seem to find correct instructions to install snap on my amazon linux 2 machine. I've done it before, but I forgot how I did it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/albuild/snap

rebuild workspace and instructions work